# Python Dictionary List Values

Tags: python, list, dict

Есть словарь dict в котором по ключу key находится значение value в виде списка list. Вопрос: как получить доступ и изменить в списке list значение второго элемента?

dict.setdefault(key, [0,1,2,3])

Пока писал вопрос, сам разобрался )))

dict[key][1] = new_value

Оставлю тут, может кому пригодится.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Пока писал вопрос, сам разобрался )))

```
dict[key][1] = new_value
```